# How to set a loop forwarding mode from one NIC to another in DPDK testpmd?

Tags: hyper-v, dpdk

Testpmd is running in a Hyper-V VM, and there are two NICs which connect to "[internal virtual switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines)". I just want to test the availability of [netvsc PMD](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides-19.11/nics/netvsc.html).

```
./app/dpdk-testpmd -l 2,3 -- --total-num-mbufs=2048 -i --portmask=0x3 --port-topology=loop
```

I have used "start" or "start tx_first", and then used "show port stats all" to check. There are no Tx-packets or Rx-packets on two NICs.

Then I used "set fwd txonly", and I could find Tx-packets on two NICs, but it is not my want. So what steps can I do?

[image: I want this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, one wants to use a packet generator on the side that is opposite to a pair of ports harnessed by `testpmd`. Such a generator starts sending packets, whilst `testpmd` simply receives them on one port and transmits them back from the other one. This *is* what `port-topology` of type `paired` stands for, and this `port-topology` is used by default in `testpmd`. Another parameter, `forward-mode`, in turn, is set to `io` by default, which means that `testpmd` does **not** change the received packets before transmitting them back (in example, does not swap MAC addresses, etc.).

However, in your case there's no packet generator employed, and that means that `testpmd` must generate and send a batch of packets itself in order to kick-start forwarding. This is accomplished by specifying option `--tx-first`.

But apart from omitting option `--tx-first` you for some reason use option `--port-topology=loop`, which might be the reason behind your setup being non-functional. Variant `loop` means that packets received by a given port (say, `Port 0`) must be transmitted back from the very same port (that is, from `Port 0`). What you might want here is `--port-topology=paired`, which, as I stated before, is anyway used by default.

So, the short of it, you should probably try running `testpmd` as follows:

```
./app/dpdk-testpmd -l 2,3 -- --total-num-mbufs=2048 -i --portmask=0x3 --tx-first
```

Please note that this way forwarding is started automatically but you get no `testpmd>` prompt to enter command in. Should you wish to start forwarding automatically and, at the same time, get an interactive command prompt, please try running `testpmd` this way:

```
./app/dpdk-testpmd -l 2,3 -- --total-num-mbufs=2048 -i --portmask=0x3 --tx-first --auto-start -i
```

Answer (score 0):

DPDK application testpmd is not a packet generator that will automatically generate and send Packets. But there is an option `--tx-first` which allows sending a burst (default 32) dummy packets from each interface.

Since your environment is physically connected this should work. But I highly recommend first check with the Linux driver whether ping or arp is able to reach the cross-connected interface first.

Note:

1. I highly recommend reading [testpmd doc](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html) for more details
2. for enabling promiscus mode use option `set promisc all on`

Comment: @lxyscls did you try running with option `--tx-first` to generate a dummy packets to fwd between ports?